# Java: Handle certain duplicates

Tags: java

I have to create a program that, giving in input various chess pieces, adds them in an array and then controls if they're valid. 
My problem is: if I give in input more than two rooks per color (for example), how can I handle this situation and show an error?

Comment: Sounds like a job for an `enum`. You might want to split the idea of "rook" into "Queen's rook" and "King's rook".

Comment: You could use a counter to remember how many rooks were passed. Or use a `List`, and everytime you add a piece, you check it's ok. BTW, you can have more than 2 rooks using promotion.

Comment: You going to have to create a system that keeps track of such things. Why are there 36 pieces? Shouldn't there be 32? Also, with pawns upgrading, couldn't 3 rooks be on the same team be valid?

Answer (score 2):

I will not do your homework for you, but some thoughts to get you going: you want to deal with the pieces of a chess game.

The very first thing to do then: create a *model* (aka **classes**) that represents that core element of your program. Meaning: your code uses 4 different variables to represent the information of a chess piece.

Instead: you could create a class that resembles a chess **piece**. Then you can create a class that resembles a chess **board**.

And now: you first check that you can translate the user input into a valid chess piece; that results in a new chess piece object. And now you ask the board: can I put this new piece on the board, at this position.

And the board simply contains a list of all previously added pieces. So the *board class* can easily decide if there is already another white rook for example. Or if the user already placed another piece on the coordinates provided for a new piece ...

A bit of code to get you started:

```
public enum Color { BLACK, WHITE; }
public enum PieceType { KING, QUEEN, ... ;

public class ChessPiece {
  private final PieceType type;
  private final Color color;
```

and so on. This should give you enough "key words" to do further research and start coding.

In other words: yes, you could do all such things on this "low level"; using 4 different *string* values to represent a single chess piece. But good OO is about creating *abstraction layers* that allow you to deal with such information in helpful ways. That sounds *complicated*, but be assured: if you *omit* this "complexity", the complexity manifests itself in the amount of code you have to write. It is much simpler to write down

```
ChessPiece newPiece = ChessPiece.from(stringRepresentationFromUser);
board.isPieceValidOn(newPiece, x, y);
```

compared to keeping track of all those string variables ...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose You are very welcome. I had some rough weeks; and try to get "on speed" again. Need to hit 50K before 6th of July ;-) ... thanks for your help!

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Obviously i never said to do the homework for me, since i've already done almost 90% of the program. My only problem was that situation. However, are you telling me that it would be better to create an abstract Piece class and then create the other classes King, Rook, etc. that extend Piece?

Comment: I am suggesting to design a proper oo model. If you want to use different classes for different pieces is a detail of that model. My main point is that you should add layers of abstraction. But of course, that is a bit late when you have 90 percent of your code already...